# Retrieve all Chats that have a certain participating user

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I have a `Chat` model in that has a field called `users`. How could I retrieve all of the `Chat`s, whose `users` field has a `CustomUser` with a certain `username`? There is a `ManyToMany` relationship between `Chat`s and `CustomUser`s.

I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=username)
chats = Chat.objects.filter(users__in=user) # doesn't work
chats = Chat.objects.filter(users__contains=user) # also doesn't work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should do the job.

```
chats: QuerySet = Chat.objects.filter(users__in=[user.pk])
```

If you have multiple users to search for:

```
users: QuerySet = CustomUser.objects.filter(...)
user_ids: List = list(users.values_list('pk', flat=True))
chats: QuerySet = Chat.objects.filter(users__in=user_ids)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should combine the querysets unless you need access to `user` for some other reason. This will reduce the number of sql queries needed to 1.

```
Chat.objects.filter(users__username=username)
```